# Stelle der Worte "sich" und "nicht"

Tags: negation, reflexive

Ich habe immer dieses Problem wenn ich auf Deutsch schreibe, dass ich die Stelle der Worte "nicht" und/oder "sich" in Haupt- und Nebensätzen nie sicher weiß.

Welcher ist richtig?

> Der Fachmann würde nicht an die Umstände sich anpassen
>
> Der Fachmann würde an die Umstände sich nicht anpassen
>
> Der Fachmann würde sich an die Umstände nicht anpassen

oder

> Der Fachmann würde den im Dokument D1 dargestellten Reisadapter nicht anpassen.
>
> Der Fachmann würde nicht den im Dokument D1 dargestellten Reisadapter anpassen.

Danke sehr

Comment: Beispiel 1: Nur Lösung 3 ist richtig. Beispiel 2: Lösung 1 ist gut. Lösung 2 ist möglich, klingt aber seltsam, außer man lässt eine Fortsetzung folgen wie "... sondern einen anderen." - Zu erklären, warum das eine richtig ist und das andere nicht, braucht es aber Kompetentere als mich. - PS: "Reis-Adapter"? Oder eher "Reise-Adapter"? - Einen Reisadapter könnte ich mir nur bei einer landwirtschaftlichen Erntemaschine vorstellen, die für anderes Getreide ausgelegt ist (Mähdrescher?), mit einem Reisadapter aber auch Reis ernten kann. Hm... gibt es so was?

Comment: Zur ersten Teilfrage: Außer Variante 3 gibt es noch eine weitere Möglichkeit, die ebenfalls korrekt ist: *Der Fachmann würde sich nicht an die Umstände anpassen*. Darüberhinaus siehe die Antwort von Matthias Brandl.

Comment: Der Kommentar von @Volker Landgraf klingt für mich auch viel natürlicher

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Die Verneinung **nicht** steht grundsätzlich vor dem Satzteil, der verneint wird.

**Die einzige Ausnahme** ist das Verb an zweiter Stelle. Soll dieses Verb verneint werden, steht *nicht* am Ende des Teilsatzes.

> Ich sehe dich.
>
> **Nicht ich** sehe dich. *(Sondern jemand anders.)*
>
> Ich sehe **nicht dich**. *(Sondern jemand anderen.)*
>
> Ich **sehe** dich **nicht**. *(Sondern ich tue etwas anderes.)*

Bei trennbaren Verben steht *nicht* jedoch der allgemeinen Regel folgend vor dem abgetrennten Teil:

> Der Fachmann passt sich an die Umstände an.
>
> **Nicht der Fachmann** passt sich an die Umstände an. *(Sondern jemand anders.)*
>
> Der Fachmann passt **nicht sich** an die Umstände an. *(Sondern jemand anderen.)*
>
> Der Fachmann passt sich **nicht an die Umstände** an. *(Sondern an etwas anderes.)*
>
> Der Fachmann **passt** sich an die Umstände **nicht an**. *(Sondern tut etwas anderes.)*

Genauso gilt das für Verbformen mit Hilfsverb.

> Sie **hat** ihn **nicht gesehen**.
>
> Du **musst** das **nicht tun.**

In Nebensätzen natürlich auch.

> Sie meint, dass sie ihn **nicht gesehen habe**.

Man kann natürlich auch mehrere Dinge auf einmal verneinen:

> Nicht ich musste nicht kommen, sondern du.

---

Das Reflexivpronomen *sich* steht immer dort, wo das Akkusativ- oder Dativ-Objekt hingehört, das durch *sich* ersetzt wird.

> Er sah **seinen Gegner** den Preis bereits nach Hause tragen.
>
> Er sah **sich** den Preis bereits nach Hause tragen.
>
> Der Kellner schenkte **dem Gast** einen Schnaps ein.
>
> Der Kellner schenkte **sich** einen Schnaps ein.

Comment: Danke, danke, danke sehr! Deutsch ist nicht einfach zu lernen, aber deine Erklärung hat mir wirklich geholfen.

Answer (score 5):

Im ersten Beispiel ist die dritte Variante korrekt:

> Der Fachmann würde sich an die Umstände nicht anpassen

Im zweiten Beispiel ist es nich so ganz eindeutig. Die erste Variante würde ich als "allgemein korrekt und neutral" bezeichnen, die zweite impliziert eine Alternative (in eckigen Klammern ein Beispiel dafür):

> Der Fachmann würde nicht den im Dokument D1 dargestellten Reis(e)adapter anpassen[, sondern den Stecker am Gerät.]